# QUANTILE FUNCTION IN TERADATA

Tags: teradata, quantile, teradata-sql-assistant

I wanna get somes categories with quantile function, but i am getting the min and max of quantile.
Example

```
SELECT * 
FROM
 ( SELECT ID, SALES, QUANTILE(5, SALES) AS QUINTIL 
   FROM 
    ( SELECT ID, SUM(SALES)  AS SALES
      fROM TABL1
      WHERE  TIME_PER = 202004
      GROUP BY 1
    ) AS TABL
 ) AS TABL
```

RESULT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNNt0.png)

Comment: Must be something else, this result can't be returned by this query-

Comment: Does the real data have a huge number of  rows with zero sales? Teradata recommends using standard SQL  `(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY s) - 1) * q / COUNT(*) OVER()` instead of `QUANTILE(q,s)`. Note that because QUANTILE is defined in terms of RANK, if there are lots of ties, the number of rows per quantile can vary. If you want arbitrary split to equal buckets in case of ties, you could use `ROW_NUMBER` instead - but then it's not a "quantile" any more.

Comment: I could find the solution, the problem was that somes sales values was null, I filtered is not null, and its ok now.